# Article: brain and bowel/ the brain and bowel/ the brain and the bowel

Tags: articles, translation

I'm a learner of English working on a translation.
Which option is the best for completing the sentence below and why?

It’s been known for a long time that human homeostasis is controlled by two main organs –

a) brain and bowel
b) the brain and bowel
c) the brain and the bowel

Comment: I think if I were to use the article for one then I'd use it for both. But you could get away with option a. The sentence does not lose anything in elegance as a result.

Comment: **C** by all means. No way I would use *A* and I would avoid *B* because of [what Misneac said](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/286821/153649). But note I differ with him/her and apparently also @WS2 on *A*. The *why* is because we often use *the* when [talking about generic things](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).

Answer (score 1):

Option C) is probably what they're looking for.

B) is incorrect since the sentence refers to "organs" plural. "The brain and bowel" as in B would imply a single entity (and sounds rather like a disgusting English pub).  C) "the brain and the bowel" designates each organ individually, and agrees with "organs". A) "brain and bowel" is also correct, but a bit curt.

Comment: I would upvote this but I deprecate option a. (American English)

Comment: How is *A* correct? An real world examples?

Comment: Sounds a good idea for a pub name to me. But how would the sign be painted? [Try this list](http://www.buzzfeed.com/lukelewis/the-23-weirdest-pub-names-in-britain#.jkonm7jrl)